# Unique identifier for user in browser without login

Tags: javascript, browser, ip

I operate a small shop online and I would like to allow users to buy stuff even if they do not have an account. For that, I need to connect a basket of selected items with a user. I thought using the ip address, but I noticed that it is actually not that easy to get the ip address. I am sure people have encountered that problem before? What is the best solution? thanks carl

Comment: And ip is not really unique....

Comment: So generate a session id on the server and use that.

Comment: Session IDs are at the basis of any server-client communication. Look it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID

Comment: You can use `window.sessionStorage` to save within a tab, or `window.localStorage` to save data browser-wide. Then check for the data when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies. Following the hints given above I solved the problem by generating a session id. In flask that's done using

```
import uuid
session['uid'] = uuid.uuid4()
```

Flask also seems to have a 'sid' element in the session object (session.sid), which apparently does the above automatically... but that did not work for me?